# tax_query not working properly with get_posts

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy, get-posts

Here are my args:

```
$args_home = array(
    'post_type' => array('news', 'jobs'),
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
            'terms' => array(4, 28),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
```

With wp_query, I got the expected result. But when I try to use get_posts, the result is different. The `operator` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange and should not happen by default. [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) uses [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). If you look at the source code of `get_posts`, all the parameters passed to `get_posts` is passed unchanged to `WP_Query` except parameters like `category` which is changed to `cat`, the `include` and `exclude` parameters to include or exclude certain posts which is changed to `post__in` and `post__not_in` respectively and `numberposts` which is changed to `posts_per_page`.

```
1839    function get_posts( $args = null ) {
1840            $defaults = array(
1841                    'numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 0,
1842                    'category' => 0, 'orderby' => 'date',
1843                    'order' => 'DESC', 'include' => array(),
1844                    'exclude' => array(), 'meta_key' => '',
1845                    'meta_value' =>'', 'post_type' => 'post',
1846                    'suppress_filters' => true
1847            );
1848    
1849            $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
1850            if ( empty( $r['post_status'] ) )
1851                    $r['post_status'] = ( 'attachment' == $r['post_type'] ) ? 'inherit' : 'publish';
1852            if ( ! empty($r['numberposts']) && empty($r['posts_per_page']) )
1853                    $r['posts_per_page'] = $r['numberposts'];
1854            if ( ! empty($r['category']) )
1855                    $r['cat'] = $r['category'];
1856            if ( ! empty($r['include']) ) {
1857                    $incposts = wp_parse_id_list( $r['include'] );
1858                    $r['posts_per_page'] = count($incposts);  // only the number of posts included
1859                    $r['post__in'] = $incposts;
1860            } elseif ( ! empty($r['exclude']) )
1861                    $r['post__not_in'] = wp_parse_id_list( $r['exclude'] );
1862    
1863            $r['ignore_sticky_posts'] = true;
1864            $r['no_found_rows'] = true;
1865    
1866            $get_posts = new WP_Query;
1867            return $get_posts->query($r);
1868    
1869    }
```

The only noticeable differences are the following two lines

```
1846     'suppress_filters' => true 
1864     $r['no_found_rows'] = true;
```

where line 1846 is the most important. By default, `get_posts` are not altered or interfered with by any filters which act on `WP_Query` because this is muted by line 1846. `WP_Query` by default is altered by any external filter that used on it, this goes for the main query and any custom query using `WP_Query`. That is why it is important to use conditionals like `is_main_query()` to target the main query specifically.

It is also very very important to know that any poorly written query that is not reset can and will interfere with both `WP_Query` and `get_posts` and thus the output from them. `query_posts` also breaks many functionalities on a page

To debug this, you will need to look for any filters that acts on `WP_Query` or the main query, also look out for any instance of `pre_get_posts`. Look for any custom query, and make sure that all instances of `WP_Query` has been reset with `wp_reset_postdata()`. If you have used `setup_postdata( $post )` with `get_posts`, then you need to reset that as well. Remove any use of `query_posts`.

If this does not work, switch to a default theme and test this again. Don't forget to clear browser and plugin caches first. Lastly, deactivate each plugin one by one and test after each one. This will show you which plugin is causing this if it is plugin related

Comment: Any feedback on this issue? Would really like to know if you where able to solve this issue as this was an interesting failure. Would appreciate your valued feedback on this issue :-)